# Blazor WASM ErrorBoundary is not catching missing dependency error (Inject attribute)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0), adding an ErrorBoundary around a Blazor component should "catch" any exceptions inside the component and render the ErrorBoundary's ErrorContent.

This seems to work OK for exceptions thrown from withing life-cycle methods.

For an App.razor file like:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ErrorContent>
        Got you!
    </ErrorContent>
    <ChildContent>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </ChildContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The following MainLayout.razor file will produce a "Got you!" output.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

MainLayout was rendered OK

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() => throw new Exception();
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work for an exception caused by a missing dependency.

For the same App.razor file, the following MainLayout will produce an unhandled exception:

```
@* MainLayout.razor *@
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

MainLayout was rendered OK

@code {
    [Inject] public IMissingDependency RequiredDependency { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

My goal is to avoid presenting the user the limited experience that comes from showing the *blazor-error-ui* and keep them always within the richer Blazor experience.

I'm hoping someone can explain why missing dependencies are not handled by ErrorBoundary, and more importantly, how to make sure those don't bubble all the way up to the user.

This section of the documentation, which is supposed to answer this question, doesn't provide any meaningful help, as it says

> the app should trap the exceptions using a try-catch statement...

but as far as I know there is no user code involved in the instantiation of the components and their dependencies.

Comment: A "missing dependency" is not something that should land in the user's lap. So this test-case doesn't convince me that there is a problem.

Comment: I agree that there are many errors that the user should never see, but I'm trying to make sure whenever there is an error I can still fully control the user experience, e.g. show a nice dialog to report the error, etc. It seems odd a missing dependency is a special case. I'm after the explanation and hopefully a solution. Notice that this is part of my question: "how to make sure those don't bubble all the way up to the user"

Comment: I don't see the "catch _any_ exceptions" phrase anywhere but I think you should read that as "during rendering".  The constructor and construction of Components seems to be out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the error is throw in the context of the Renderer, not the component.  Unlike the DI container, where dependencies are injected in the CTor, the Renderer does the injection by detecting any properties with the `Inject` attribute, getting the relevant object from the `IServiceProvider`, and setting it manually: somewhere between CTor and `Attach`.

I don't think there's a graceful way to capture Renderer exceptions into the UI.

I also agree with @H H comments.  This should not be a user issue.  Any missing DI definitions should be detected a long time before going live!

Answer (score 0):

> how to make sure those don't bubble all the way up to the user

If you inject `IEnumerable<IMissingDependency>` like this

```cs
[Inject] private IEnumerable<IMissingDependency> RequiredDependency { get; set; } = default!;
...
RequiredDependency.First()... //will throw here and can be captured
```

you will be able to capture the error during rendering instead of crashing the application.

Of course that may not be to your liking.

Comment: Not very likeable, but interesting and helpful!